# How to delete the selected item from listview(sqlite database) in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I inserted text items to the database. When I click on remove button the selected item is not removed from list view.

```
 private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

        list l = new list();

        l.list1 = list_view.SelectedItem.ToString();       
        list_view.Items.Remove(l.list1);
        List<list> del = await con.QueryAsync<list>("delete from list where list1='" + list_view.SelectedItem + "'");
        if (del.Contains(list_view.SelectedItem))
        {
            list_view.Items.Remove(list_view.SelectedItem);
        }
```

(Here list1 is the column)

Comment: is it not reflecting on the UI or list_view itself?? Did you debug and check the list_view items?/

Comment: Yes it is not reflecting in UI, Ya I also placed breakpoint but no result

Comment: Can you show me your XAML bindings to listview

Comment: I didnot bound any data. When I click on add button a popup with textbox will be displayed. When I input some text the string will be displayed in listview and also added to the db                                                                                       `var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
            var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

            list l = new list();
            l.list1 = text_input.Text.ToString();   
            list_view.Items.Add(l.list1);
            await con.InsertAsync(l); `

Comment: what does l.list1 have after assigning selected value

Comment: The string values inserted to list1.The inserted values should be deleted and then updated in a button click. How...

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of List.

ObservableCollection implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface which notifies the UI when something in the list is changed.